# Radio buttons spacing out

Tags: html, radio-button

The radio buttons are looking weird, and I don't know why. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want that third one in line but I don't know how.

This is the code for all three buttons. I tried using `<pr>` tags but this didn't work.

```
<td><input type="radio"
           id="examtype" 
           name="examtype" 
           value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br />
<pr></pr>

<td><input type="radio"
           id="examtype" 
           name="examtype"
           value="A2" /> : A2<br />
<pr></pr>

<td><input type="radio"
           id="examtype"
           name="examtype"
           value="AS"/> : AS<br />
<pr></pr>
</tr>
```

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed. Your question has nothing to do with Java programming that I can tell.

Comment: Better use http://jsfiddle.net to show us your actual code.

Comment: What does your CSS look like

Comment: What the hell is a `<pr></pr>` tag?

Comment: Your `td` tags aren't closed.

Comment: I copied someone on youtube for <pr> tags, he said it was paragraph tag, and yes thanks for picking that up, my <td> tags are not closed, don't know how i didn't spot that. And Css? i don't know what that means mate, my tutor told us the task and to research the answers for it, he never teached us anything, which i totally disagree with.

Comment: @user3258519 Paragraph tags are just `<p>`

Comment: @user3258519 the way you make paragraphs is either by putting content *between* a `<p>` and `</p>`, or by putting a `<br/>` (so without `</br>`) below your text. The `<br/>` will insert a new line, not a paragraph, but it does basically the same in your situation here. So in your example, since you've got `<br/>` already, the `<p>` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: well what should i use to get the button next to the As label

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `pr` is a tag... I'm guessing you meant to type `tr`, or `br`, or maybe even `pre` (but that doesn't make sense). Regardless, using the correct `table` structure, the elements can be neatly positioned inline without any weird jumps like in your picture:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="GCSE" />: GCSE
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="A2" />: A2
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="AS" />: AS
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/5syuV/4/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, finaly after 2 week of reviewing my code it works!